# Is it possible to Manipulate Message body on Message Read with Officejs

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on an Outlook add-in using OfficeJS.

There does not seem to be a setAsync method on Office.context.mailbox.item.body when reading a message. I can understand why this generally makes sense.

Is there any way an add-in can alter the body text when reading a message?

I do not want to alter the original message on the server.

Comment: No. That's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature: Manipulate Message in Read Mode, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.